# superlevel sets of a concave function are convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm reading a paper where it's written that the superlevel sets of a concave function are convex. First what's a "super"level? And why is this true ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$. The superlevel set $S(\alpha) \subset X$ is the set of values in the domain for which the function value is at least $\alpha$:
$$S(\alpha) = \{ x \in X : f(x) \geq \alpha\}. $$
This set is indeed convex, which can be proven using the concavity of $f$. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $x_1,x_2 \in S(\alpha)$, and $\lambda \in [0,1]$, then:
$$f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2) \geq \lambda f(x_1) + (1-\lambda) f(x_2) \geq \lambda \alpha + (1-\lambda)\alpha = \alpha.$$
Therefore, $\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2 \in S(\alpha)$.

Comment: The function value is *at least* $\alpha$.